# Error Deploying Cloud Function from gitlab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I am trying to deploy a cloud function via gitlab using a new service account (Not using default service account). It has the cloud functions developer role but it is still failing with below error:

The error below includes a user as cloud-functions-mixer. I haven't configured anything like that in my repo and not sure why it is coming up.

First of all, running the suggested command doesn't even work because the suggested syntax is bad . I have tried running the below command but it’s not right

> Error: googleapi: Error 403: Missing necessary permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for cloud-functions-mixer on the service account project-test-tf-02@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
> Grant the role 'roles/iam.serviceAccountUser' to cloud-functions-mixer on the service account project-test-tf-02@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
> You can do that by running 'gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding project-test-tf-02@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --member=cloud-functions-mixer --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser'.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not doing what the error tells you to do? Or what are you asking at all?

Comment: Yea I tried executing the command but cloud-functions-mixer is a user unknown to me. Is it a some user in cloud function ?

Comment: Please try to re-deploy because the permissions "iam.serviceAccounts.actAs" which is missing as per error will be automatically granted this permission after the service account creation. Please refer to the documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google's instructions about the `cloud-functions-mixer` are **wrong**. What you actually need to do is replace the string `cloud-functions-mixer` with the name of the service account that is *building or deploying* your function.

The following user-defined service accounts will be used in an example:

- `my-cloud-function@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is the service account that your function runs as.
- `build-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` is the service account that builds/deploys your Cloud Function

The command to run is:

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding 
  my-cloud-function@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
   --member=serviceAccount:build-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
    --role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/add-iam-policy-binding)

Or, in Terraform, you would need a resource like this:

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "opentok_webhook_mixer" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.my_cloud_function.id
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
  member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.build_service_account.email}"
}
```

You'll have to update the names of the service account resources.

This approach also works for Google Cloud Build.